# Update C# compiler for ASP.NET ASPX pages using updated C# features

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on an older website running on .NET 4.8 and using C# 11, but still using ASP.NET technology. I've introduced a few `record` classes throughout the codebase, but when I reference those in an ASPX page, it blows up at runtime with the error:

```
CS1545: Property, indexer, or event 'AppCode.CoreUser.Email' is not supported by the language
```

The detailed compiler output shows that the machine running IIS is running a version of `csc.exe` for the on-the-fly compilation which only supports C# 5:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /t:library {...}

Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.8.3761.0

for C# 5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

I presume the issue is that records are using features that aren't supported under C# 5. But I've googled and haven't figured out how to get the ASPX pages to build using a later version of the C# compiler.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, if you using a asp.net web site application, then everything is compiled local before publish. However, if your using a asp.net web "site", then yes, pages are compiled on the web server, and if  you use some of the newer features in .net, then you have to be careful.  Updating IIS would get you a later compiler for this. But, if this is a hosting plan system, you as a general rule can't change that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're already using the Roslyn CodeDOM providers? If not, you should follow the guide for [Enabling the .NET Compiler Platform (“Roslyn”) in ASP.NET applications](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/enabling-the-net-compiler-platform-roslyn-in-asp-net-applications/)
.

Once you have that installed, you should have a `system.codedom` element in your `Web.config` similar to this:

```xml
<system.codedom>
  <compilers>
    <compiler extension=".cs" language="c#;cs;csharp" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:7.3 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701;612;618" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=3.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <compiler extension=".vb" language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008,40000,40008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=3.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```

Note that the `compilerOptions` attribute contains a compiler switch with `/langversion:7.3`. That's the latest officially supported language version for .NET Framework.

There's nothing stopping you from bumping this to a newer version, e.g. `/langversion:11`. But the problem is that the Roslyn CodeDOM provider comes with an older version of the compiler (v3.6.0) that only supports C# 8.

There's [a newer version of the package in the works](https://github.com/aspnet/RoslynCodeDomProvider/issues/144), but the timeline is unclear and it probably won't support the latest version of the language anyway (as it's not officially supported by Microsoft.)

Fortunately for us, the Roslyn CodeDOM provider has an MSBuild property you can set to specify a custom compiler location. In combination with the `Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset` NuGet package and [`GeneratePathProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#generatepathproperty), we can use this to download a newer version of the compiler and make the Roslyn CodeDOM provider use that version instead.

First, add a reference to the newest `Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset` package in your `csproj`:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset" Version="4.5.0" IncludeAssets="none" PrivateAssets="all" GeneratePathProperty="true" />
</ItemGroup>
```

By specifying `IncludeAssets="none"` and `PrivateAssets="all"`, we ensure that nothing from the package is consumed or flowed transitively. It's purely to download the compilers inside the package.

By specifying `GeneratePathProperty="true"`, it allows us to reference the package location in order to set the `RoslynToolPath` later:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <LangVersion>11</LangVersion>
  <RoslynToolPath>$(PkgMicrosoft_Net_Compilers_Toolset)\tasks\net472</RoslynToolPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Once that's in place, you should be able to go back to your `Web.config` and bump the language version to C# 11: `/langversion:11` and recompile everything.

When you start using language features from newer versions of the language, you'll probably start getting compiler errors about missing types etc. In that case, I can recommend installing the wonderful [PolySharp](https://github.com/Sergio0694/PolySharp) package, which will take care of polyfilling most of the missing types (by using source generators) for you.

Comment: A newer version of the Roslyn CodeDOM provider package has been released (4.1.0). However, even when using this in combination with PolySharp, I am still unable to use a C# 11.0 language feature in .cshtml files. The error I'm getting is: 'Constructors of types with required members are not supported in this version of your compiler.'

Comment: Yeah, hence my comment: "it probably won't support the latest version of the language anyway (as it's not officially supported by Microsoft.)"